# Undefined Method in view of All Users and All Articles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

Very new to Ruby here and trying to set up the classic User-Articles MVC structure but using Objectives and Key Results instead.

**Problem:**

```
NoMethodError in Home#index - undefined method `keyresults' for nil:NilClass
```

**Question:**

How do I define the relation between Objectives and Key Results in the controller?

I assume that's the problem here.

Any explanation on how to proceed would be amazing!

I tried:

```
@objectives = Objective.all.include(:keyresult)
```

But that didn't work.

**Goal:** on the index page list all objectives and their associated key results:

> Objective 1
>
> - Key Result 1
> - Key Result 3
>
> Objective 2
>
> - Key Result 2
> - Key Result 4
> - Key Result 5

**objective.rb**

```
class Objective < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :objectives_keyresults, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :keyresults, through: :objectives_keyresults
```

**keyresult.rb**

```
class Keyresult < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :objective
```

**home_controller.rb**

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
   @objectives = Objective.all
  end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<%- model_class = Objective -%>

<% @objectives.each do |objective| %>
  Objective:
  <%= objective.title %>
  Key Result:
  <% @objective.keyresults.each do |keyresult| %>
    <%= keyresult.title %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**schema.rb**

```
create_table "keyresults", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.string "title"
 t.integer "objective_id"
 t.index ["objective_id"], name: "index_keyresults_on_objective_id"
end

create_table "objectives", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.string "title"
end

create_table "objectives_keyresults", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.integer "objective_id"
 t.integer "keyresult_id"
 t.index ["keyresult_id"], name: "index_objectives_keyresults_on_keyresult_id"
 t.index ["objective_id"], name: "index_objectives_keyresults_on_objective_id"
end
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your block `each` you have used `@objective`. It's `nil`

Use `objective`.

```
<% @objectives.each do |objective| %>
  Objective:
  <%= objective.title %>
  Key Result:
  <% objective.keyresults.each do |keyresult| %>
    <%= keyresult.title %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @mechnicov. That indeed took the error away :) However, it's now not displaying the list of key results, just the objectives. Is that because I have to define keyresults in the controller?

Comment: Sure, definitely will do. My experience on SO is still so low that they don't show my upvotes yet :(   Anyways, thanks for the thought. Not working with objectives_keyresults but keeping it simpler indeed made it work.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @mechnicov 's answer:  When inside a loop, use the local variable name `objective` and not the instance variable name `@objective`.  The `NoMethodError` is telling you exactly what the problem is.  The object you've called the method on is nil since it has not been defined.

Here's a simple example of the actual problem:

```
[:a, :b, :c].each { |item| print @item.capitalize }
# NoMethodError: undefined method `capitalize' for nil:NilClass
# the instance variable @item is an instance of NilCLass

[:a, :b, :c].each { |item| print item.capitalize }
# ABC=> [:a, :b, :c]
```

In rails, you define your model object instance variables inside the controller.  When iterating over them in a view, you use the local variable assigned in your loop.